# Demons' Dungeon

Tags: logical-deduction, language

After winning the Fairy Logician's competition, you are reverse-summoned to a room with 5 portals at equal distances from each other. They are all locked,but fortunately, there is a logical demon in front of each portal, they are willing to unlock  one portal for you. The problem is that only 1 of these portals is the exit while the others will send you to your certain death.

The demons are all knowing, but incredibly lazy. They will only allow you to ask 3 questions. They will only provide a 1-bit (yes/no) answer. And if your question requires more than 25 english words* to perfectly grammatically express they won't answer it.

Oh yeah, one more thing, though demons are supposed to lie, all but one of them are to lazy to too that, and will answer truthfully.

Can you get out alive, Logician Adventurer?

---

(*) words are *all* you can use, expressions like ∀ε ∃δ have to be expressed like this: "There is a delta for every epsilon", which is 7 words already, and you have 25.

Disclaimer: this puzzle is based heavily on [the one by stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43806/find-the-correct-door)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the correct door!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43806/find-the-correct-door)

Comment: I can ask three times to one demon or should I ask three different demons ? Do the demon, who lies, is predeterminded, or is it randomly selected ?

Comment: dude at least give me credits or something. I worked hard to build my puzzle.

Comment: I was just doing that, honest.

Comment: @Arbitrary Kangaroo, you can ask any demon, one demon at a time, and the dutiful (lying) demon is always the same one.

Comment: Well let's be positive. I will take that as you liked my puzzle to that extent, which shall make me happy.

Comment: @mr23ceec What would happen if the answer is neither yes nor no ? e.g (To a question whose answer is 1): What is the answer - reply yes if 2 and no if 0 ?

Comment: If you're wondering why the change of setting, there was originally a joke about how doors/portals were equidistant because of "higher demonsions", but I decided to remove it (and several others, equally bad)

Comment: @mr23ceec: What are you saying ? I don't understand. What's the answer to my comment ?

Comment: Either I don't see the difference to the other puzzle except different wording of restrictions, or if it is intentional that you place no other limitations on the questions than yes/no and max. 25 words then it's trivial with multiple statements in a question.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo I wasn't answering you. That is actually a good question. The spirit of the puzzle is that you get 1 bit, so let's say "demons always default to 'no' unless the answer is 'yes'"

Comment: @mr23ceec: (I don't understand what gibber I'm writing) What is not a lie and not a truth, but itself is a statement ?

Comment: @Arkku 
a) that is correct: just formalizing restrictions.
b) how do multiple statements help?

Comment: @mr23ceec re. multiple statements: `you will lie XOR statement B` gives the truth about statement B no matter whether they lie or tell the truth.

Comment: @Arkku Ok, what if "demons are also paranoid, and will talk freely about others but not about anything relating to themselves" was added? ("what will This Other Demon say if I asked him if the Riemann Hypothesis is correct" is about others, whereas "what would This Other Demon say if I asked him if you're a liar" is relates to the demon himself.)

Comment: @mr23ceec Depends on what you can ask about others (e.g., can you ask "Would (other demon) answer yes if asked: X?"). I think if you add enough restrictions then the solution is again trivial (i.e., you can't get out alive), and if you don't it's very hard to prove there is no solution. Or, is it telling about themselves if you ask something like the question in my answer to the other puzzle (which does _not_ reveal whether they are a liar or not)…

Comment: @Arkku Yes, according to my (poorly though out) intent that was a valid question, and the situation where you ask A "what if I asked B what would happen if I asked C what..." are supposed to be prevented by the 25 word rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any demon.

> 1. If I asked you if one of these 3 portals (point) was the exit, would you say yes?
> Because the question loops itself, it doesn't matter if the devil is a liar or not, they will be telling the truth, and I'll know which group, of either 2 or 3 portals, the exit is in. Point to one of the portals from that group. Ask any devil.
> 2. If I asked you if this was the exit, would you say yes?
> Again, loops itself, doesn't matter if the devil's a liar. If it's the exit, we can leave. If it isn't, and this is the group of 2 portals, we know the other is the exit. If this is the group of 3 portals, we have to point at one of the remaining ones, and ask any devil.
> 3. If I asked you if this was the exit, would you say yes?

Now we know, and can leave.

Comment: One bit answer, not "What would you say" type stuff.

Comment: Right, editing now

Comment: I did not think this through. But you solved the puzzle I posted.

Comment: Also technically you're not supposed to point (only words, remember?) but seeing as how no other way to identify portals is provided...

Comment: I have 8 spare words to define a number system in question #1 if needs be, but yes there is no given way to identify the portals. Perhaps if they were coloured...

Comment: e.g., "the portal behind you or the two immediately to the left of it" replaces "one of these 3 portals", then you are at exactly +8 words… For the other questions, go to the demon in front of the portal and ask "the portal behind you" instead of "this" (you have words to spare).

Comment: Really you could leave the third question out all together, once you have your second answer the process of elimination will give you the answer to the third.

Comment: @Forral Not for the case where answer 1 is "yes" (one of three) and answer 2 is "no" (not the first one of three), then you still have two left.